# Javascript only running on first view (first page) - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile, mobile, initialization

Possible related error from firebug: ... Cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

I am making this app that requires you to type the answer of a certain ´level´ to go to the next one. The answer is in a list and should only display on exact match for the search. Below is my html for the first two pages and my javascript for hiding the answer untill exact match is provided.

However it ONLY works on the first view (page) and doesn´t work on the second, third, fourth and so on! I really spent a loooong time trying to fix this and I am lost. The only thing that worked for me so far was a prefetch-data="true", but it only works to some extent and stops working after page 3. Other then that I´ve tried to implement many solutions I found here and there but none do what I want. I hope there is some simple thing I am doing wrong.

Why does the script only run on the first view and how do I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PARestaurant</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="style" href="images">
            <style type="text/css"></style>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>      
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

<!-- Page Index
Home Page
Level Two 
Level Three
Level Four
-->

<!-- -----------------------------------------------------------Home Page----------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <div data-role="page" id="232114125125124124" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" align="center">
        <h1>Star Riddle</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" align="center">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h2>Ready when you are!</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul class="whatever" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"
                        data-filter-reveal="true" data-inset="true"
                        data-filter-placeholder="">
                        <li data-filtertext="Green"><a href="#32432532462362345325235235">You are a genius!</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="blue"></div> <h2>+</h2> <div id="yellow"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" align="center">
            <h1>Level 1</h1>
        </div>
        </div>

<!-- -----------------------------------------------------------Level Two----------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <div data-role="page" id="32432532462362345325235235" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" align="center">
        <h1>Star Riddle</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" align="center">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h2> You know what to do! </h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="whatever" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-inset="true" data-filter-placeholder="">
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 1"><a href="#232114125125124124">Click me to go back!</a></li>
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 3"><a href="#534264363464327327">Up you go!</a></li>
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 4">You have to struggle a bit</li>
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 5">Not so fast</li>
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 6">No No NO!</li>
                            <li data-filtertext="Level 7">Stop it...</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>`enter code here`
                    <div><p>Where do you wanna go?<p></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" align="center">
            <h1>Level 2</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT BELOW

```
exactMatch = function( text, searchString ) {
    return !( text.toLowerCase() == searchString );
    };
$(function () {
    $(".whatever").listview('option', 'filterCallback', exactMatch);
});

}
```

Comment: Instead of $(function () {} use pageinit for each page (http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/pageinit/) because the listviews are not initialized until you visit each page the first time.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I am a bit new to this and don´t know how to implement this properly? Should I just add something to my script or to every single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(function () {...
```

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", function( e ) {    
    $(e.target).find(".whatever").listview('option', 'filterCallback', exactMatch);
});
```

pageinit runs once as each page you visit is initialized for the first time.

Comment: I asked so many different people including some "experts" and tried so many different things and you just fixed it. Seems very usefull for running javascript for specific recurring elements on multipage document!